# Scipy in python (v2.6) script not recognized in Abaqus (v6.12)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a python (v2.6) script which I wish to run with Abaqus (v6.12) on a windows 7, 64 bit machine. The python script calls on numpy and scipy.

I installed the numpy (v1.7.2) and scipy (v0.8) modules compatible with python (v2.6) for Abaqus (v6.12) as per some instructions I found

http://polymerfem.com/showthread.php?1626-Using-numpy-or-scipy-within-abaqus-python

I understand that Abaqus (v6.12) has numpy (v1.4) built-in and I cannot get it to see the higher version of numpy I downloaded.

Also when I call for example "scipy.optimize" in my script I get the following import error:

ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a a valid Win32 application.

I am an academic user of Abaqus so unfortunately that means I cannot access support

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a 32 vs 64-bit problem. Make sure that both Python and Abaqus have the same architecture, e.g., 32-bit or 64-bit.